# how can i mimic the conversation history of chatGPT with langchain openAI API?

Tags: openai-api, langchain, chatgpt-api, py-langchain

in chatgpt 3.5 the max tokens are 4096 , but it looks like from one end it is able to receive long prompts and generate some long responses, and from the other side it is able to hold the context of all the messages in the same chat.
i wonder how it can be mimicked if i want to build a chatbot on top of openAI , using langchain for example. i have build it with conversation history of 1 (meaning it remembers the last message) , so i have shorter context , but still i fail on max token limit.

Comment: you need to control your response from prompt, also you can define well structured prompt role that will help getting appropriate response from LLM.